# Why does my shutdown script not work?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im running it on Windows 8.1 if I run the shutdown command without the script, it works. But when I run it from this script there is some wrong syntax shown in the cmd.... thanks for help

```
@echo off
TITLE shutdown timer

SET /P minutes=Enter minutes till shutdown or "no" to stop running shutdowns: 

IF "%minutes%" == "no" (
    shutdown /a
    echo shutdown aborted
) ELSE (
    SET /A seconds = %minutes% * 60
    shutdown /s /f /t %seconds%
)
pause
```

Comment: And what is the exact error you get? "Something wrong" is no proper error description.

Comment: you need delayedExpansion -> http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Agreed, please post the text of the syntax error

Comment: the error is no argument, and its shown how to use the command as if you would type shutdown /?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
TITLE shutdown timer

SET /P "minutes=Enter minutes till shutdown or "no" to stop running shutdowns: "

IF "%minutes%" == "no" (
    shutdown /a
    echo shutdown aborted
) ELSE (
    SET /A seconds = minutes * 60
    shutdown /s /f /t !seconds!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the seconds out of the condition and it works:

```
@echo off
TITLE shutdown timer

SET /P minutes=Enter minutes till shutdown or "no" to stop running shutdowns:
SET /A seconds = %minutes% * 60

IF "%minutes%" == "no" (
shutdown /a
echo shutdown aborted
) ELSE (
shutdown /s /f /t %seconds%
)
pause
```